# CodeIgniter3 - routes do not work when serving app as example.com/codeigniter

Tags: apache2, codeigniter-3

I have an application based on codeigniter3 framework hosted on VM bitnami lampstack. Initially I have set up the apache to serve the application from the root domain: *example.com/*. Furthermore I have an .htaccess file for removing the index.php from url as per [CI3 documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html).

The content of my .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|static|vendor|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond  %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond  %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Recently I have changed the apache configuration as such that the application to be served from *example.com/codeigniter* and although the main page is loading correctly all the links in application are broken and when clicked they return not found message: *The requested URL /about was not found on this server*.

My routes in config/routes.php looks like this:

```
##---------------- Home Routes ------------------##
$route['about'] = 'home/about';
$route['login'] = 'home/login';
```

The link in the navbar is set like this:

```
 <li class="navbar-item" role="presentation">
     <a class="navbar-link" href="/about">
         <i class="far fa-address-card"></i> About
     </a>
 </li>
```

When the link is clicked it is pointing to *example.com/about* instead of *example.com/codeigniter/about*. But even if I add as `href="/codeigniter/about"`it is still does not work. Seems to me that the somehow the codeigniter fails to map the path to the correct controller.

The problem is solved in part by adding index.php before the route (*e.g. example.com/codeigniter/index.php/about*). It is loading the correct page but fails to load the static files (css, js and images files).

So seems to me that problem results from .htaccess file but I do not know how to fix it. What should I add to or remove from that file?

Do you have any ideea how this problem may be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set base_url()?

Comment: Yes! base_url() is set as follows:$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/codeigniter';

Comment: I have switched to bitnami vhosts configuration and it works using subdomains: codeigniter.example.com but I do not know hot make it work based on the prefix configuration